# (a != null) or (null != a)

Tags: java, variables, null

Is there any difference in comparing a variable with `null` or comparing the `null` with a variable?

For example, which comparation is better `(a != null)` or `(null != a)` ?
I've read somewhere that the second one is faster but didn't find the reason for this.

Comment: Yoda conditions FTW :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined (link accessible to 10k users only)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, none is faster. That's a plain lie. There is no advantage of using the second version. Only making readability worse.

This all came from C, where you could erroneously write

```
if(x = 3)
```

instead of

```
if( x == 3)
```

Some people thought that it'd be best to write the constant first, in which case if you wrote `=`instead of `==`, you'd get a compiler error. So some sources recommended writing

```
if(3 == x)
```

Some people didn't know why this was necessary and carried on and generalized this idea to constructs and languages where it makes absolutely no sense. IMO it didn't make a lot of sense in the original C context either, but that's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Actually, there *is* a speed difference. Testing `null == var` is one instruction slower, because the null must be pushed onto the stack. Not much, but not identical either.

Comment: @Bohemian: That's the job of the optimizer to take care of such microoptimizations

Answer (score 9):

Even if there *were* a difference in speed, I'd expect it to be entirely insignificant in 99.99% of apps. As it is, I wouldn't expect there to be *any* speed difference. Personally I find `if (a != null)` more readable - and readability is *much* more important than performance in most cases.

Comment: well I find `null != a` more readable, matter of habit perhaps :-)

Comment: @aishwarya: A habit developed from C or C++? It may make sense to use comparisons that way to be defensive (although modern compilers pick up the accidental assignment, IIRC) but I *believe* most developers who don't have a background where there's a definite benefit find the "variable first" form more readable.

Answer (score 4):

You might only want to use a literal before the variable when doing operations with strings.

`if("abcd".equals(name))` doesn't throw a `NPE` where as `if(name.equals("abcd"))` does if at all `name` were to be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually done to prevent accidental assignment instead of comparison:

```
( a = null ) //will not give error

( null = a ) //will give error
```

I'm fairly sure efficiency is not a reason, and if it were, an optimizer would render the code the same in binary.

Comment: We cannot make this mistake in Java but C/C++

Comment: Ah! I meant that both of your statements will be error due to java compiler. `if (a = null)` just fine in some C/C++ compiler.

Comment: @H3S: We can make that mistake in Java, too, if we try hard enough: `Boolean a = true; if (a = null) {}`. No compile error, but blows up with an NPE at runtime.

Comment: @Thilo: Oh, sorry! I forgot the `Boolean` type

Comment: @H3S you're right - excluding Thilo's example, which is a good one - I didn't think of that.

Comment: Well, you could make this `if(variable = null)` mistake for any non-primitive type.

Comment: @adarshr I don't think you could. In Java, that would also yield an error, as types aren't implicitly cast to boolean. I think that was H3S's point.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no difference what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

not really, not in java now anyways. in older days, may be C, you could accidentally forget the exclamation mark and the code would compile fine. basically, `a = null` would be taken as an expression that assigned null to `a` and always evaluate to true (because assignment was successful).

Today's compilers are far more robust. Although, old habits die hard and I still write `null != a` :-)

Comment: Sorry to be so late into the conversation, but your remark about "an expression that assigned null to `a` and always evaluate to true (because assignment was successful)" is not correct. It evaluates to whatever the value of null is (so it can be false if null is false).